# Simple regex making me want to scream

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to get the `64-birmingham` out of

```
... name="title" /> <link href="http://www.domain.com/cities/64/deals/147943-local-coupon-book" rel="canonical" /> <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-type" /> <link href="/deals/images/mobile/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" /> <link href="http://www.domain.com/cities/64-birmingham.atom" rel="alternate" title="Birmingham, AL" type="application/atom+xml" />...
```

with this regex

```
preg_match('#//www\.domain\.com/cities/(.+?)\.atom#is', $response, $slug);
```

It keeps picking up `64/deals/147943-local-coupon-book" rel="canonical" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern, even with the `+?`, will start matching at the first `www.domain.com/cities` URL, then match all the way up through the `.atom` at the end of the second, different URL.

A different pattern like

```
'#//www\.domain\.com/cities/([^"]+?)\.atom#is'
```

would force a match to be contained within one set of double-quotes, preventing the matching from running wild over most of the string.

Answer (score 0):

By default the regex pattern will get the longest string possible. You could use something like:

```
#//www\.domain\.com/cities/([^\"]+?)\.atom#is
```

instead.

What I did was instead of asking for 'anything' with '.' I asked for anything except a double quote.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

`$get = preg_match_all("|href=\"http://(.*?)/cities/(.*?).atom\"|", $response, $slug);`

where the 64-birmingham will be `$get[2][0];`